# How does T-SQL implicit conversion / overload resolution work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, overload-resolution

I've been toying around with T-SQL in an attempt to understand the implicit conversion and overload resolution rules, but somehow it seems to work a bit strange...

Context:

- Data type conversion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx
- Data type precedence: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx
- Abs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx

Basically the latter tells you that `abs` will work on int, float, decimal, etc. So let's see how that works:

```
declare @foo2 sql_variant;
set @foo2 = abs(4);
select sql_variant_property(@foo2, 'BaseType')

-- result: int. OK, apparently we have an int overload. As expected.

declare @foo2 sql_variant;
set @foo2 = abs(cast(4.0 as float));
select sql_variant_property(@foo2, 'BaseType')

-- result: float. OK, apparently we have a float overload. As expected.
```

Now, according to the implicit type conversion table, we are allowed to implicitly convert stuff. We're going to check this by converting a varbinary to int, which should happen according to the type precedence rules:

```
declare @foo varbinary(4);
set @foo = cast(4 as varbinary(4));
select @foo + 2;

-- result: int. OK, as expected.
```

From this result I would expect the following to work as well:

```
declare @foo varbinary(4);
set @foo = cast(4 as varbinary(4));
select abs(@foo);
-- result: error: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with float
```

Stuff I don't understand here (the question):

- Why does the implicit conversion pick the 'float' overload of the 'abs'? Is this just a random overload? Or perhaps the overload that's highest in the precedence list (which happens to be 'float')?
- Why isn't implicit conversion applied from varbinary -> int? After all, it's a perfectly valid conversion.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN for Abs:

```
Arguments

numeric_expression

    Is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data type category.
```

I guess that calling Abs( varbinary ) would try to convert the varbinary to an exact numeric or approximate numeric data type.

Float is at the top of Data Type Precedence for these types so there is the problem I guess.

**UPDATE with my logic**

```
declare @foo varbinary(4);
```

Declare a varbinary variable.

```
set @foo = cast( 4 as varbinary(4));
```

Set to this variable a value by performing an explicit cast from int to varbinary which is perfectly doable.

```
select sql_variant_property(@foo, 'BaseType')
```

This shows that the variable is of type varbinary.

```
select abs(@foo);
```

Try to run abs on varbinary.
The error message is clear:

```
Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with float
```

So my guess is that abs is trying to implicit convert varbinary to the first of the Data Type Precedence for exact numeric or approximate numeric data types which is float.

This conversion fails according to `CAST and CONVERT` chart.

Comment: Good call, but apparently it doesn't work like that. The first expression returns `int` and the second expression returns `float` -- if what you say is true, both should return `numeric`.

Comment: @atlaste So `set @foo = cast(4 as varbinary(4));` is int? Because running `select sql_variant_property(@foo, 'BaseType')` returns varbinary. I'm a little bit confused on your comment.

Comment: Ah wait, I misunderstood you. Yes, it appears that it picks the least likely overload candidate (e.g. the numeric expression at the top instead of the one closest to the original type)... That's what I meant with "Or perhaps the overload that's highest in the precedence list (which happens to be 'float')?" However, that's just a guess - I have no clue on how this would behave with multiple parameters etc.

Comment: @atlaste I've updated my answer with my thoughts. Hope it is wright to help our friend.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've got this right! Comments appreciated.

You've found the conversion and precedence MSDN pages so let's take your example apart.

```
declare @foo varbinary(4);
set @foo = cast(4 as varbinary(4));
```

Now, what type is foo?

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo,'BaseType')

--------
varbinary
```

Good so far so good.  But what's 'in' @foo ?

```
SELECT @foo
----------
0x00000004
```

Now, `ABS()` accepts a `numeric` - a floating point number:

[image]

What does `4.00` look like compared to `4`? Let's try:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 4.00) ,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 4);
------------------   -----------------------
0x0302000190010000   0x00000004
```

See the internal representation of `4.00` is different to `4`? It's storing  precision, scale and the value whereas your 'int in a varbinary' isn't.

And that's why the conversion fails. `ABS()` accepts a `numeric`, your 'wrong format' `varbinary` cannot be coerced to a `numeric` as it's not one, it's some other representation - we know it represents an int but SQL Server doesn't.

If you want to add a floating point number to an int that's 'inside' a varbinary, you have to do something like

```
select CONVERT(INT, @foo) + 2.0
```

Back to your example:

```
declare @foo varbinary(max);
set @foo = cast(4.00 as varbinary(max));
SELECT ABS(@foo+2.0)
----------
6.0
```

`4.00` is converted into a `varbinary` in the correct internal format, and happily coerced into a `numeric` by the `ABS()` call. Happy days.

Comment: @foo+2.0 ( varbinary + float ) = float according [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) You perform an implicit convertion.

Comment: True, but @foo doesn't contain a float.

Comment: @LesH Nope, that's not it. Actually 2.0 is a decimal. You can check that by using an intermediate (implicit cast to) `sql_variant`: 'SELECT sql_variant_property((@foo+2.0), 'BaseType')' --> numeric. As for abs, you can also check that `abs` accepts more than just a numeric -- it also accepts float, int, etc. _without_ implicit conversion!

Comment: @atlaste yes of course.  But the reason the conversion fails is because the varbinary isn't storing a representation of a floating point number.

Comment: The point is that you perform an implicit conversion. I believe the question was why abs( varbinary ) throws an error.